# Parent activity onCreate() called on back press (Android)

Tags: android, back-stack

I have 3 activities - A, B and C.
From A I start B, and from B I start C, i.e
A -> B -> C.
On going from A to B, I deliver an intent to B - let's call this intent  intentA.
When I go from B to C, and then from C to B by pressing back button, 'onCreate()' of B is called again and intentA is delivered to B again, even though I didn't pass any intent to B while pressing back button in C.
What do I do so that 'onCreate()' of B is not called when pressing back button in C, or even if it is called, intentA is not delivered to it?
I tried setting launchmode of B to 'singletop'/'singletask' in manifest, but they didn't work.
I tried using 'finish()' in onBackPressed() method in C, but didn't work.

I tried other solutions as well using answers to similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them worked.

Any solution?

Also, I'm using Dexter library to ask for permissions in my custom dialogbox, and I'm using screen transition animations as well. Could these be causing the issue?

Comment: How to pass the intent? Using any Button? or anything else

Comment: I'm passing the intent while starting B from A, and receiving the intent in onCreate() of B.

Answer (score 0):

For launching ActivityC from ActivityA with adding ActivityB to backstack,
use startActivities with array of intentA and intentB as parameter